# How can I unbalance double columns in revtex4?

Tags: vertical-alignment, two-column, revtex

It seems that revtex4 tries to automatically balance the lengths of the two columns on the last page of a double-column document.  I would like to know how to turn this off.  Unfortunately, all the Googling I do for this is pages telling me how to turn it on.  I've tried the multicol package, but it seems that it interferes with some of the internals of the revtex package, so I'm hoping there's a simpler way to get it done.

In case it helps, here is how I start my .tex file:

```
\documentclass[amssymb,aps,nofootinbib,letterpaper,10pt,twocolumn]{revtex4}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tricky. You'll probably want to include the `nobalancelastpage` option:

```
\documentclass[amssymb,aps,nofootinbib,letterpaper,10pt,twocolumn,nobalancelastpage]{revtex4}
```